# A rock, paper, scissors tournament is encoded as a bracketed array of games

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Hi I need to create a rock, paper, scissors tournament that is encoded as a bracketed array of games -that is, each element can be considered its own tournament.  I need to work with something like this:

[image]

Under this scenario, Dave would beat Armando (S>P), Richard would beat Michael (R>S), and then Dave and Richard would play (Richard wins since R>S); similarly, Allen would beat Omer,Robert would beat John, and Allen and Robert would play (Allen wins since S>P);and finally Richard would beat Allen since R>S, that is, continue until there is only a single winner. I am wondering what would be the best option to create the algorithm using a 2d array or a list. Any comments or example on how to create it would be really appreciate.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of posting images please post the text as code to keep the formatting. Besides that I'd use a list rather than a 2d array. Now create some algorithm and show us what you got.

Comment: Typical breadth-first tree-visiting algorithm. Can be easily found in any book in procedural or recursive way.